# VB.net how to wait for user to select an Excel cell

Tags: excel, vb.net, vsto, user-input, user-interaction

I have created a VSTO project in Visual Studio with a Ribbon and a Form. There is a button on this form which I want when a user clicks on it, it waits for user to select a single cell from the workbook which this add-in is used in it.

I am currently at designing stage and have not much code written. Any key ideas to achieving this? Should I use **Application.SendKeys** method? Any other/better ideas?

Thanks

My Ribbon Code so far:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon

Public Class Ribbon1

    Private Sub Ribbon1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e 
    As RibbonUIEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As 
        RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim f As New Form1
        f.Show()
    End Sub

End Class
```

My Form Code so far:

```
Public Class Form1

    'Variables for my "Custom Vlookup Function"
    Dim RHeader As Excel.Range 'Reference Header
    Dim SRange As Excel.Range 'Seleceted Range
    Dim ColNo As Integer 'Column number ahead

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application
    Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook = 
    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
        Handles Button2.Click

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Wait for the [Worksheet.SelectionChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.selectionchange) event which is fired when the selection changes on a worksheet.

Comment: How should I integrate your suggestion with my VB.net project WinForm?

Comment: But in your post you've mentioned that a VSTO project was created in Visual Studio with a Ribbon and a Form.

Comment: Should I make a loop in my WinForm to catch the **Worksheet.SelectionChange** result? is _Worksheet.SelectionChange_ in a Workbook return anything or is it just Do something after an event occurs?

Comment: Anyway, your add-in can wait for the event and communicate with a standalone WinForms application using standard .net communication mechanisms like WCF and etc.

Comment: Users may click a button on the windows form application which can call the VSTO add-in to wait for the event in Excel. As soon as the event is fired your VSTO add-in can communicate back to the windows forms application.